# Does centrifuging the bacteria culture removes bacteria leftovers?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, cell-culture, carbohydrates

Usually, we centrifuge bacteria culture to either replace the media, control its density (OD), ..etc. I know that when centrifuging the cells are pushed to the bottom while the media (solution) remains at the top. However, let's say the bacteria was left to culture for a few days and the bacteria metabolism releases some carbohydrates as an output (e.g. Cyanobacteria).

Would those carbohydrates remain at the bottom with the bacteria cells or will they stay with media at the top where we can pour them?

Comment: What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Answer (score -2):

Centrifugal pelleting is density based. Under general media conditions and centrifugation, most secreted carbs will remain in the supernatant.
[image]

Comment: Correct answer, +1. The only way to pellet ("precipitate") dissolved compounds is a low enough temperatures, in conditions where sugars would crystallize out of solution. It would then be possible to centrifuge them into a pellet. Also, routine centrifugation in my experience leaves some viable bacteria in the supernatant, so if you wish to have a cell-free supernatant, it is always good practice to additionally filter it post-centrifugation. PS. I see you've been downvoted, likely by someone looking for the addition of credible reference/citations.

Comment: @SPr [There are methods to pellet dissolved compounds](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2711687/).